# Xcode 4.5 - OS X Cocoa Application - Basic Web View: Load Google when opened

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.5

I'm trying to create an extremely basic OS X Cocoa Application that when opens loads http://www.google.com. As basic as possible (no back or forward buttons, etc.).

I have little experience with Xcode 4.5 and I can't find any tutorials regarding a web view for OS X Cocoa Application AND Xcode 4.5. I was able to find a tutorial and create a web view for an iOS web view. I took what I learned but didn't get very far.

Here's what I did so far:

- Created New OS X Cocoa Application in Xcode 4.5.2
- Added a WebView object to the Window object

Based on the iOS web view tutorial I assume all I need to do is add a couple lines of code and it should work?

This is the code I used in the iOS web view (ViewController.m):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

[myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been stuck on this all night.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After adding the `WebView` to your main window, you'll want to make sure you've added the `WebKit.framework` to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries for your project otherwise you'll get a linking error.

.h:

```
@class WebView;

@interface MDAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

Assuming you've created an `IBOutlet` for the `WebView` named `webView` like in the code above, you can load a URL using the code below:

.m:

```
@implementation MDAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/"]];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

Sample GitHub project: https://github.com/NSGod/WebViewFinagler

Comment: To have the WewView autosize on the main view do: In Xcode, go to File Inspector window and uncheck checkbox given for "Use Autolayout" and switch to Size inspector you will see the autoresizing window.

Answer (score -1):

add `self` keyword to following line

```
[myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

like this

```
[self.myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

try following code,it work for me,just tested

> > 1) create new project 
> >     2) select ViewController ,goto xcode menu
> >     Editor->Embed in->Navigation controller 
> >     3)declare myWebView property  in ViewController.h

in ViewController.m write following code

```
   self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 
   self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];
   NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
   [self.myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Comment: Which file do I add this to?

Comment: @user1822824:in ViewController.m

Comment: I only have AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m

Comment: I don't see that. I am doing this for desktop NOT iOS.