# OS X Cocoa App - Web App - Creating a users variable in Preferences?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am creating a Mac Web App where I have followed along from here:
[stack overflow os x web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474142/xcode-4-5-os-x-cocoa-application-basic-web-view-load-google-when-opened)

Now I have got my web app running fine, but now I want to customise it a little for my needs and am not sure where to start at all.

Basically, in the .m file I have the my code which ties to the URL I have set with in it. e.g.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/"]];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}
```

I want to create a Preference Menu where user can enter in the URL required rather than a preset one such as my localhost:8888. Obviously, it would need a variable where user enters URL in pref panel and on save reloads the web app page.

Any help here would be great. Like I said no coding experience really, so be gentle.

Thanks

### EDIT

OK, so I have added this to my AppDelegate.h

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *prefURL;
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender;
```

and assigned this to my text field in the preferences window.

How do I change the url with this in the AppDelegate.m, I was thinking something like this (I know it's wrong though)

```
URLWithString:.stringValue*PrefURL]];
```

All I need to do is add the text from the NSTextField to the URLWithString:

Comment: Simplest way - in this case - would be to add a `NSTextField` above your `WebView`. Connect it (in your header file) with an outlet (CTRL-DRAG the text field into the header file to create an outlet or an action) and use the .stringValue of this outlet in your URL request.

Comment: Hey DigiMonk, Thanks for the reply. Is there anyway to be more specific, I get the idea what needs to happen but don't know how to implement it. Do you know of any tutes that go through this in particular? Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit of my progress. Thanks

Comment: '_prefURL.stringValue' gives you the text that is in the text field as a string. You can also define an action for your text field.

Comment: Like this:  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: _prefURL.stringValue ]];

Comment: ok so. i have changed the url to the _prefURL.stringValue as u stated above. Now I am trying to get a action for it. I added this: - (IBAction)test:(id)sender; under @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *prefURL;
 in the .h file. But still nothing. When I run it, it builds successfully, however page is white as expected, I enter in a url e.g. http://google.com in the pref text field but still nothing. Do i need to make it reload the page after or have I stuffed up the action? Thanks